# Encode multiple categorical columns into numerical in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Order status | Shipping mode |
| --- | --- |
| Complete | Standard Class |
| Pending | First Class |
| Pending Payment | Same day |
| Closed | Second class |

i want to convert this into:

| Order status | Shipping mode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

How can we achieve this in R?

Comment: Do you really want to transform your variables into numeric? O would ordered factors do the trick? Why would you do that?

Comment: I want to apply decision tree regressor model on the data, thats the reason for transforming into numeric

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your variables to `factor` by providing the `levels=` in the right order and simultateously coerce them `as.numeric`.

```
dat <- transform(dat, 
                 order_stat_num=as.numeric(
                   factor(order_stat, 
                          levels=c("Complete", "Pending", "Closed", "Pending Payment"))),
                 shipping_mode_num=as.numeric(
                   factor(shipping_mode, 
                          levels=c("Standard Class", "First Class", "Same day", "Second class")))
)
dat
#         order_stat  shipping_mode order_stat_num shipping_mode_num
# 1         Complete Standard Class              1                 1
# 2           Closed    First Class              3                 2
# 3         Complete   Second class              1                 4
# 4          Pending    First Class              2                 2
# 5         Complete    First Class              1                 2
# 6           Closed Standard Class              3                 1
# 7           Closed   Second class              3                 4
# 8  Pending Payment Standard Class              4                 1
# 9           Closed   Second class              3                 4
# 10          Closed   Second class              3                 4
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(order_stat = c("Complete", "Closed", "Complete", 
"Pending", "Complete", "Closed", "Closed", "Pending Payment", 
"Closed", "Closed"), shipping_mode = c("Standard Class", "First Class", 
"Second class", "First Class", "First Class", "Standard Class", 
"Second class", "Standard Class", "Second class", "Second class"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
categorical_col = c("Order status","Shipping mode")
data[,categorical_col] = lapply(data[categorical_col], factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values aren't leveled, you may use `dplyr::dense_rank` also

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~dense_rank(.)))

  Orderstatus Shippingmode
1           2            4
2           3            1
3           4            2
4           1            3
```

Similarly

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(as.factor(.))))
  Orderstatus Shippingmode
1           2            4
2           3            1
3           4            2
4           1            3
```

dput used

```
df <- read.table(text = "Orderstatus    Shippingmode
1 Complete  'Standard Class'
2 Pending   'First Class'
3 'Pending Payment' 'Same day'
4 Closed    'Second class'", header = T)
```